# 'str' object has no attribute 'to_string' in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
| column1  | column2        |
| -------- | -------------- |
| abc      | 1              |
| def      | 16             |
| ghi      | 982            |
```

I'm selecting a row and using to_string(index=False) on it.

```
something = df.loc(df['column2'] == 982]
print(something.column1.to_string(index=False))
```

I'm doing this repeatedly over a large dataframe and 99 times out of 100 it's fine. Every once in a while though, I get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_string'`.
There's nothing unusual about the data in the instances where this happens. What could be causing this?

Comment: No idea - I can't reproduce when running your code in a loop 10k times.

Comment: But, I do recommend you do `something.column1.iloc[0]` instead of `something.column1.to_string(index=False)`

Answer (score 2):

One case I can think of where this might happen if your column name happens to be the name of a string property of the DataFrame itself, since you end up calling `to_string()` on an actual string.

Here's an (unlikely) example to demonstrate.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ['foo', 'foo', 'bar'], "_info_axis_name": [1,2,3]})
df._info_axis_name.to_string()

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_string'
```

Perhaps check your column names are not clashing, or use `df['col']` instead of `df.col` to select the column?